# How to implement batchWriteItem for deleting data in DynamoDB [Java]?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am very very new to DynamoDB. I have a lot of stale data in a table. I want to delete it in batch. What I have done till now is that I have queried the Table using GSI. Now, since there is not much relevant content of using batchWriteItem in Java, can someone please help me. A code example would be appreciated.

I have tried googling a lot and have read AWS documentation for batchWriteItem. But they don't have any code examples as such.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `addDeleteItem` in the `BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest`

```
    var builder =
            BatchWriteItemEnhancedRequest.builder();

    
    items.forEach(item -> builder.addWriteBatch(WriteBatch.builder(ItemEntity.class)
            .addDeleteItem(<key or item>)
            .build()));

    enhancedClient.batchWriteItem(builder.build());
```

All of this is from the [v2 sdk version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/dynamodb)

Comment: Thanks, Borislav...this approach worked 
I can't upvote this because not enough reputation...